# Pushing Boxes, help me solve this graph problem!

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

Given a directed, acyclic graph with nodes representing boxes/objects at rest and edges that point to neighbouring boxes/objects in direct contact. Each node will be assigned a number that represents an external force exerted on the box/object. Positive forces will flow in edge direction and negative against edge direction, that is to say, boxes can only be pushed by another box, but not pulled. Forces are one-dimensional.

You can imagine that depending on the forces and how the boxes are connected, forces will add up or cancel out.

How can I find the resulting forces to determine which parts of the graph start moving, and which will remain at rest?

See drawing for illustration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snil4.jpg

Comment: why is there an edge from node -4 to 5? also why did you choose dag to solve this problem?

Comment: The edge is there, because the two boxes are in contact. Intuitively I agree, that this edge is not necessary, given the assigned forces, but if we added another node after 5 with force -6, you can see that the edge is required. I choose a dag because it captures all the relevant information. Also I was hoping that this problem translates to a known graph problem (which I am not aware of).

Comment: since you are aware of forces cancelling out, you can try to solve it using vectors(1-D)

Comment: It‘s not obvious how the forces should cancel, because nodes are coupled and how forces should propagate cannot be decided locally, at least I think so.